# Office App in VS2013 build fails with 0 errors

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, ms-word

I created an Office App using the new JavaScript library and it was working fine when I last used it, several months ago. I am now re-visiting this project but I cant get it to build. I get 0 information out of VS. 0 errors, 0 warnings and 0 messages.

**Attempted solutions:**

I tried creating a new project from scratch and still have the same issue.

I checked for updates on windows and in VS and all extensions.

I even tried turning up the verbosity levels on the build output, but they dont help at all.

I have tried googling but I either dont know the right terms or nobody else has asked yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
If you havent heard of [Apps for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220060.aspx) its just html5/js/css3 inside a pane in word/excel etc. The api is nice and easy to use.

Edit: so I just found out that it cant even do a clean. wtf? something is really wrong here.

Edit 2: I tried the old "del /s /q *.user" and the files are gone but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the bin and obj folders in the 2 projects that make up an office app did the trick. Maybe a combo of something I did earlier also. Either way it works now, and I didnt have to restart windows :P